# i am facing below error when trying to run the app that "App is keep stopping" how to resolve this?

Tags: android, firebase

'''2020-06-21 13:22:53.293 9305-9305/? E/le.androideati: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-06-21 13:22:54.521 9305-9305/com.example.androideatit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.androideatit, PID: 9305
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androideatit/com.example.androideatit.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #40 in com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #40 in com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at com.example.androideatit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5                                                                    // error is here
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:532)
at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
2020-06-21 13:22:54.522 9305-9305/com.example.androideatit E/AndroidRuntime:     at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.(FButton.java:52)
... 28 more
'''

Comment: This typically means your build system is missing dependency that has info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Comment: what does this have to do with firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

the error is here

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in
com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #40 in
com.example.androideatit:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class
info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
```

In the resource file loaded by MainActivity, i.e. layout/activity_main at the line 40 there is a component, `info.hoang8f.widget.FButton` that surely are missing libraries declared in you gradle.build file, something like

```
implememntation 'info.hoang8f.widget.FButton:FButton:1.0.0'
```

or something like that

Comment: no had libraries declared in gradle.build file as implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

Comment: In fact, there is the error. try to put: compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5' in gradle.build app level and mavenCentral() in the repositories in gradle.build project level

Comment: actually earlier i  was tried as compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5' but it was not working so that's why i put it as implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5